# In MicronautProject, using hibernate specifications throw exception: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, hibernate, micronaut-data

I'm studying micronaut. when I use hibernate in micronaut project.Everything is OK.I study in docs.micronaut.io. However I use specifications. throw exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:473)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations.getCurrentEntityManager(HibernateJpaOperations.java:620)
    at io.micronaut.data.spring.jpa.intercept.FindAllSpecificationInterceptor.intercept(FindAllSpecificationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
    at jpatest.repository.BookRepository$Intercepted.findAll(Unknown Source)
```

### Controller

```
@Controller("/book")
public class BookController {
    @Inject
    BookService bookService;
    @Transactional
    @Get()
    HttpResponse book() {
        return bookService.findAll();
    }
}
```

### Service

```
@Singleton
public class BookService {
    @Inject
    BookRepository bookRepository;
    public HttpResponse findAll() {

        Specification<Book> bookSpecification = (Specification<Book>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"),2);
        List all = bookRepository.findAll(bookSpecification);
//        Iterable<Book> all = bookRepository.findAll();
        return HttpResponse.ok(all);
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {
    Book find(String title);
}
```

### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private int pages;

    public Book(String title, int pages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}
```

### Application.xml

```
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'jpatest.entity'
```

When i use @Transactional it doesnt work.I sure using

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Maybe I need configue sth

Comment: The question mentions `Application.xml` but then shows YAML code.  Is that YAML code in `src/main/resources/application.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing  the micronaut-spring dependency. if I import it, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using `micronaut-data-spring` in your Micronaut service shouldn't use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` with Micronaut Data and in your case, you don't have to use any `@Transactional` annotation (Spring or otherwise).  Your `BookRepository` should automatically be made transactional.

Comment: thank u. I try to use JPA Specification in Micronaut Project.I need to import micronaut-data-spring and org.springframework:spring-orm. Studying in here:[micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#spring](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#spring)